# python .py file execute and debug parts

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a .py file open in Visual Studio Code. However, I'm missing the jupyter notebooks functionality to execute cells/debug. Is there any way I could execute and debug single parts of the whole .py script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be great if you could specify exactly what you mean by missing the jupyter notebook's functionality, because you could use the `#%%` magic line depending on the kind of limitation you have.

If your need is just to run code line by line or by chunks you can do so using VS Code quite easily. You just need to have a terminal window open, select the part of the code you want to run, and press `⇧ + ↩`(Mac). Maybe your key binding is different, but you can check it on Preferences: keyboard shortcuts under Python: Run Selection/Line in Python Terminal

Answer (score 0):

You can bebug the file by placing breakpoints in it, and then copy & paste portions of the file into the DEBUG CONSOLE to execute them (or press continue, etc.).

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial